# Method returns wrong value - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Why does this method always return true, even when the editTexts have nothing in them?

```
private boolean allFieldsFilledOut() {
        boolean allFieldsFilledOut = false;
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        EditText passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassWord);
        EditText image = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProfilePicture);

        if (name.getText().toString() != "" && passWord.getText().toString() != ""
            && image.getText().toString() != "") {
            allFieldsFilledOut = true;
        }
        else {
            allFieldsFilledOut = false;
        }

        return allFieldsFilledOut;
    }
```

One thing I have been wondering about is, I create this activity through an intent a few times per use case. Am I referencing an old activity's editTexts? Should I be killing the activity when show a new activity? `findViewById(R.id.editTextName)` gets the application resource, with no reference to this specific activity. Is there another way to reference these editTexts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compare string, use equals is compare string's value, use == is compare string's address

this mean (name.getText().toString())'s address != ("")'s address so that it always true

```
name.getText().toString() != ""
```

if you want to compare string's value, you need to use equals

```
if (name.getText().toString().equals("") == false && 
    passWord.getText().toString().equals("") == false && 
    image.getText().toString().equals("") == false)
```

Comment: Good answer...just a note. You also could use "!" instead of comparing to `false`. `if (!name.getText().toString().equals(""))`. Also, switching it around is safer as it protects against a `NPE`, `if (!"".equals(name.getText().toString()))`